# How to get the value of fields.function value in SQL query?

Tags: odoo

I want to use SQL query to improve performance of report but got stuck on how to get the value of fields.functions in SQL query (that is a function field with many2many type and none relation table), how can I write SQL query in this case?

```
def _compute_lines(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    result = {}
    for invoice in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        src = []
        lines = []
        if invoice.move_id:
            for m in invoice.move_id.line_id:
                if m.account_id != invoice.account_id:
                    continue
                temp_lines = []
                if m.reconcile_id:
                    temp_lines = map(lambda x: x.id, m.reconcile_id.line_id)
                elif m.reconcile_partial_id:
                    temp_lines = map(lambda x: x.id, m.reconcile_partial_id.line_partial_ids)
                lines += [x for x in temp_lines if x not in lines]
                src.append(m.id)

        lines = filter(lambda x: x not in src, lines)
        result[invoice.id] = lines
    return result




'payment_ids': fields.function(_compute_lines, relation='account.move.line', type="many2many", string='Payments', groups='base.group_user'),
```

Answer (score 1):

> computed fields are not stored by default, they are computed and
>   returned when requested. Setting store=True will store them in the
>   database and automatically enable searching

Source: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields